# SQL Query Search doesnt use joined table

Tags: php, mysql

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'fetch_schedule')
    {
        $output = array();

        $order_column = array('dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_name','dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_datetimestart', 'dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_day', 'dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_start_time', 'dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_quota', 'dosen_table.dosen_name', 'dosen_table.dosen_degree', 'dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_sumpeserta');
        
        $main_query = "
        SELECT dosen_schedule_table.*, dosen_table.*, DATE_FORMAT(dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_datetimestart,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i %W')
         AS dosen_schedule_datetimestart, DAYNAME(dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_datetimestart) as dosen_schedule_datetimestartday FROM dosen_schedule_table 
        INNER JOIN dosen_table 
        ON dosen_table.dosen_id = dosen_schedule_table.dosen_id 
        ";

        $search_query = '
        WHERE dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_datetimestart >= "'.date('Y-m-d').'" 
        AND dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_status = "Active" 
        AND dosen_table.dosen_status = "Active" 
        ';

        if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
        {
            $search_query .= 'AND ( dosen_schedule_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $search_query .= 'OR dosen_schedule_datetimestart LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $search_query .= 'OR dosen_schedule_day LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $search_query .= 'OR dosen_schedule_start_time LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $search_query .= 'OR dosen_schedule_quota LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $search_query .= 'OR dosen_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $search_query .= 'OR dosen_degree LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $search_query .= 'OR dosen_schedule_sumpeserta LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%") ';
        }
        
        if(isset($_POST["order"]))
        {
            $order_query = 'ORDER BY '.$order_column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
        }
        else
        {
            $order_query = 'ORDER BY dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_datetimestart ASC ';
        }

        $limit_query = '';

        if($_POST["length"] != -1)
        {
            $limit_query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
        }

        $object->query = $main_query . $search_query . $order_query;

        $object->execute();

        $filtered_rows = $object->row_count();

        $object->query .= $limit_query;

        $result = $object->get_result();

        $object->query = $main_query . $search_query;

        $object->execute();

        $total_rows = $object->row_count();

        $data = array();

//Fetch Data Kegiatan
        
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $sub_array = array();
            
            $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_schedule_name"];
            
            $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_schedule_datetimestart"];
            
            $sub_array[] = (new DateTime($row["dosen_schedule_datetimestart"]))->format('l');
            
            $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_schedule_start_time"] .' - '. $row["dosen_schedule_end_time"];
            
            $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_schedule_quota"];
            
            $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_name"];

            $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_degree"];
            
            $sub_array[] = $row["dosen_schedule_sumpeserta"];


            

            $sub_array[] = '
            <div align="center">
            <button type="button" name="get_appointment" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm get_appointment" data-dosen_id="'.$row["dosen_id"].'" data-dosen_schedule_id="'.$row["dosen_schedule_id"].'">Get Seated</button>
            </div>
            ';
            $data[] = $sub_array;
        }

        $output = array(
            "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
            "recordsTotal"      =>  $total_rows,
            "recordsFiltered"   =>  $filtered_rows,
            "data"              =>  $data
        );
            
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

1. I'm Confused why my `$search_query` doesnt use joined table from `$main_query`, its causing i can't search by DATE and DAYNAME in `DD-MM-YYYY` format, but when i search using `YYYY-MM-DD` format its showing the right result, whether i already formatting the DATETIME column to `'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i %W'`
2. I think my $Result sub array not yet effective for this kind of scenario, is there any other possible scenario?

Comment: Dump out `$object->query` and inspect it

Answer (score 0):

you need to try this query:

```
<?php

$search        = $_POST['search']['value'];
$limit         = $_POST['length'];
$start         = $_POST['start'];
$order_index   = $_POST['order'][0]['column'];
$order_field   = $_POST['columns'][$order_index]['data'];
$order_ascdesc = $_POST['order'][0]['dir'];

$sql = "
SELECT 
    dosen_schedule_table.*,
    dosen_table.*,
    DATE_FORMAT(dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_datetimestart,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i %W') AS dosen_schedule_datetimestart,
    DAYNAME(dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_datetimestart) as dosen_schedule_datetimestartday
FROM 
    dosen_schedule_table 
INNER JOIN 
    dosen_table ON dosen_table.dosen_id = dosen_schedule_table.dosen_id 
WHERE ( 
        dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_datetimestart >= "'.date('Y-m-d').'" 
        AND dosen_schedule_table.dosen_schedule_status = "Active" 
        AND dosen_table.dosen_status = "Active"
    )
AND
    (
        dosen_schedule_name LIKE "%$search%" OR
        dosen_schedule_datetimestart LIKE "%$search%" OR
        dosen_schedule_day LIKE "%$search%" OR
        dosen_schedule_start_time LIKE "%$search%" OR
        dosen_schedule_quota LIKE "%$search%" OR
        dosen_name LIKE "%$search%" OR
        dosen_degree LIKE "%$search%" OR
        dosen_schedule_sumpeserta LIKE "%$search%"
    )
ORDER BY 
    $order_field $order_ascdec
LIMIT 
    $start, $limit
";
```